# How would I add input validation?

Tags: c#, validation

How would I add user input validation to the following code? not sure whether to use try and catch or if there is some other way that would be great, cheers :)

```
private static int ReadInteger(string prompt)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt + ": > ");
        return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    private static string ReadString(string prompt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt + ": > ");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static double ReadDouble(string prompt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt + ": > ");
        return Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    private static DateTime ReadDate(string prompt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt + ": > ");
        return Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sticking with Convert then you'd probably use a try catch. Perhaps adjust your ReadXxx methods so they don't return unless the input is valid:

```
private static DateTime ReadDate(string prompt)
{
   while(true){
      Console.WriteLine(prompt + ": > ");
      try{
         return Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
      } catch(Exception) {
         Console.WriteLine("Couldn't understand that as a date, try again ");
      }
   }
}
```

The only way for the user to escape this loop is to enter a valid date

If you don't want to use `try` you could look at the likes of `TryParse` on int, DateTime etc - it returns false if the parsing failed, which you can use in a loop control to keep the loop going while parsing didn't work, e.g.:

```
Console.WriteLine(prompt + ": > ");
int x;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x))
  Console.WriteLine("Bad int, try again> ");
return x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and TryParse.

```
private static int ReadInteger(string prompt)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt + ": > ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var ok = int.TryParse(input, out var result);
        if (ok) return result;
        Console.WriteLine("That isn't a valid integer.");
    }
}
```